# What, in your code, can stop javascript from enabling in your browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment

I have an issue that I can't find out anywhere on google. I'm having a hard time figuring out what's wrong with my deployment. I have a react app that works just find locally, but doesn't want to display javascript in production. Note that javascript is enabled in the browswer. But the code is echoing that javacript is not enabled. Have anyone ran into this problem and know what could be going on?

Comment: Check the console. Are you getting any errors? Is your JS actually loading?

Comment: Yes, this is the error I get in the console..  Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Comment: But, I get that same error on the working file on my local host